# Android workmanager detect when worker is killed by system

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I use workerManager in my application. I have a worker that once a day downloads data from the server and shows the download status in notification and then closes it. On average, it works for 5-10 seconds. I have complaints from users on Android 9 that the notification hangs in notifications and nothing happens. I have a hypothesis that the system kills the worker and that cannot tell notification that the boot process is complete and delete it. Could you tell me, please, as can be catch destruction worker system? Thanks

Comment: difficult to say without seem the code of your Worker and how you queue the request. Are you handling the `onStop()` method in your worker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `onStopped` method (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker.html#onStopped()) and cancel your notification there.

Comment: It seems that `onStopped()` is called only when *it is told to stop*. I want to listen for the event when the `Worker` has finished the work. Basically inside the `Worker` class constructor I bind to a service, and when the work is done I want to unbind from that service. I am not sure how that can be done. There is no `onDestroy` as it is inside `ÌntentService` for instance. How to do it here inside `Worker`?